# After render jsf - empty tbody element

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, jsf

Drawing table means JSF
The table includes only the headers. After rendering is still a empty tag TBODY

JSF:

```
   <h:dataTable>
         <h:column>
             <f:facet name="header">
               <h:outputText value="col1" />
             </f:facet>
          </h:column>
          <h:column>
             <f:facet name="header">
               <h:outputText value="col2" />
             </f:facet>
          </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

html result:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <span>col1</span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <span>col2</span>
      </th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> </tbody>
</table>
```

How to write JSF code  that would did not created an empty TBODY element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your dataTable. The only things you defined were:

- I want a table;
- I want the table to have 2 columns;
- I want the first column to have the title "col1";
- I want the second column to have the title "col2";

And that's exactly what JSF rendered for you. You didn't pass any data to the dataTable. You have to use the `value` attribute and pass a list.

[BalusC has an old article, but still usefull, about Using datatables.](http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2006/06/using-datatables.html)